# Running two instances of Rstudio simultaneously on Linux

Tags: r, rstudio

I've got a lengthy process running in Rstudio and I would like to open a separate session of Rstudio while the first one is running. I know I can run R from the command line to get as many sessions as I want, but I wanted to know if it is possible for me to do this in Rstudio on a Linux computer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Just start another instance by typing rstudio on the command line.

Comment: @infominer Wow, I never would have guessed it would be that easy, thanks! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: This does not work any more. New instance simply opens connects to the existing instance and opens a file for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@infominer suggested a good solution, which is to simply type rstudio in the command line. That's what I ended up doing

Comment: If you do `nohup rstudio &` then you can close the commandline window afterwards.    (BTW, thanks: I hadn't realized it was this simple either!)

Answer (score 1):

Another convenient way to deal with this is to start a seperate R-instance in the terminal by typing simply

```
R
```

and from there just run the script that has a lengthy process with

```
source("path-to-your-script/your-script.R")
```

you can than continue to edit and work with your two scripts in the already opened R-Studio editor window.